# Axiomatic Systems, finding a relation

Tags: logic, relations

I am currently taking Axiomatic Systems and I am struggling with this chapter of material. One of the homework questions is: "Let A = {3,17,29,45} and B = {4,6, 22,60}. A relation R from A to B is defined by aRb if and
only if a + b is a prime. i) Find the relation R. ii) Is R a function from A to B?" But I do not know how to even begin to approach this question.

Comment: Do you know what the definition of a relation is?

Comment: I know the formal definition my professor gave us within the definition for a function, "A function _f_ from _A_ to _B_  is a **relation** from  _A_ to _B_ such that for every x that exists in _A_, there is a unique corresponding element _y_ that exists in _B_"

Comment: In your comment, you've quoted the definition of "function", which assumes that "relation" has already been defined. That will be useful (indeed necessary) for part (ii) of the problem, but for part (i) you'll need the definition of "relation", which should have been given earlier in your class notes or textbook.

Answer (score 2):

There are $4 \times 4=16$ ordered pairs of one element from A and one from B with the A element first.  These are candidates for elements of your relation.  As an example, $3R4$ because $3+4=7$ and $7$ is prime, so $(3,4)$ is one element of the relation.  Go through the rest of the pairs  and check them.  That will give you the relation $R$.  Now apply the definition of a function that you quoted to answer the second part.

Comment: Perhaps change "candidates for your relation" to "candidates for elements of your relation". Your shorter wording is clear enough for someone familiar with relations, but it appears the OP is unfamiliar with them.

Comment: @AndreasBlass:  Good idea.  Thanks.